# I could hardly believe it but(when?) I found their tallest player was shorter than I

Tags: conjunctions

> I could hardly believe it but I found their tallest player was shorter than I.

Generally in sentences  with inversion the pair of conjunction with *hardly* is *when* e.g.  *Hardly had I arrived home when my phone rang.* So going by this isn't the *but* in above sentence incorrect and its better to use *when* here or it's an exception here ?

Answer (score 1):

The word **hardly** is being used in a different sense in your two examples. In the first, it qualifies your ability to believe something. In the second, it states a fact, meaning "just as I arrived home, ..."

Using **when** is correct

> I could hardly believe it when I found their tallest player was
>   shorter than I.

Although **than I** is formally correct, **than me** is more usual, so I would modify the sentence in steps:

> I could hardly believe it when I found their tallest player was
>   shorter than I am.
>
> I could hardly believe it when I found their tallest player was
>   shorter than me.
>
> I could hardly believe it when I found I am taller than their tallest
>   player.

Using **shorter** makes the sentence harder to understand, since it is about being tall, not being short.

Back to the question, **but** is used to contradict something, or give an opposing view. There is none here to challenge. Perhaps if you said

> I believed their players were very tall, but I found I am taller than
>   their tallest player.

the **but** would be well placed.

Comment: So using 'but' is incorrect in first sentence ?

Answer (score 0):

1. **hardly**, when it introduces a clause whose verb is in the present perfect or past perfect, refers to the completed state expressed by the perfect as being *not-quite-complete*. There is inversion in the clause so introduced:

> Hardly ***had* we *come*** in the door... when the phone rang.
>
> Hardly ***had* we *taken*** our seats when the curtain opened and the play began.

2. **hardly**, when it does not introduce the clause but appears in a normal adverbial position and modifies the verb, expresses the idea of *not-quite*.

> I **could** hardly **believe** my eyes ... I was taller than their tallest player.

Comment: But this doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @user212388. It does answer your question. There is no inversion in your example sentence ("I could...") and **hardly** does *not* introduce the clause, so why do you wish to treat the sentence as an example of the first usage?  The word **hardly** in your example is being used in the second way. There are two independent clauses yoked by **but**.

Comment: I agree that the sentence form is different but question was if using 'but' is correct here, in the second example you gave, you have omitted 'but' and didn't talk about using 'but' in your answer so it felt a little ambiguous to me if 'but' here is correct or not.

Comment: @user212388: I  intentionally did not join the two clauses  in order to show that they were independent of one another, and not interdependent as they are in the first usage.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence could be correct with either the word "when" or the word "but", though the emphasis would be different depending on which word is used.

If the sentence uses the word "when" then the second half of the sentence would be simply giving the situational context to the the first half of the sentence. That is to say, it would be describing the situation in which you could hardly believe. The situation was when you found out that their tallest player was shorter than you.

If the sentence uses the word "but" then the second half of the sentence becomes a contrast to the first half of the sentence. The first half is saying that something was unbelievable, while the second half is saying that something is true. Thus the complete sentence is saying that something is true *despite* the fact that it is unbelievable. In this case it is unbelievable that their tallest player could be shorter than you, but it is still true as you have found out.